# Modem Manager can't find HP lt4132 LTE modem (22.04)

Tags: network-manager, internet, mobile-broadband, modem-manager

After I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04, my modem seems to be missing. At least network/modem manager is not able to recognize it anymore. It is weird and I don't know what to do.

I tried two commands and got:

```
mmcli -L >> No modems were found

lsusb >> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 03f0:a31d HP, Inc HP lt4132 LTE/HSPA+ 4G Module
```

I suppose it could mean that there is some sort of problem with identifying the correct connection mode for the modem to work. But again, I have no idea what might cause the problem.

But because of my un-educated guess, I tried following the steps in [How to use HP lt4132 mobile device on Linux](https://www.casesup.com/category/knowledgebase/howtos/how-to-use-hp-lt4132-mobile-device-on-linux), but with no success: Deconfiguring and enabling MBIM mode instead of ECM mode gave me an error.

I tried two commands and got:

```
grep lt4132 /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product >> /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/product:HP lt4132 LTE/HSPA+ 4G Module

echo 0 > sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/device/bConfigurationValue >> bash: sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/device/bConfigurationValue: No such file or directory
```

So, here I am, asking for your guidance. Maybe using other versions of modem/network manager might help?

Thanks for helping out! :-)

Comment: I could not solve the problem and therefore decided to roll back to Ubuntu 20.04 instead.

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be an issue with USB Modeswitch missing the configuration for lt4132
see my post in the USB Modeswitch forum:
https://draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2710&p=19981#p19981

if you are good with different versions, in an older version of usb_modeswitch the configuration might work, maybe you could share the configuration here and try. I am not aware how to download an old version at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i have solved my issue, maybe it helps someone else:

```
book:~# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/hp-lt4132.rules
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="a31d", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}!="3", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}:="0"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="a31d", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}!="3", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'sleep 1; echo 3 > %S%p/bConfigurationValue'"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="a31d", ATTR{cdc_ncm/ndp_to_end}=="N", ATTR{cdc_ncm/ndp_to_end}:="Y"
book:~#
```

afterwards reboot and see your Broadband appearing :)

Answer (score 0):

@ant0nwax' solution also works for a Huawei ME906s LTE M.2 module (which is identical to an HP lt4132 LTE/HSPA+ 4G module). You just have to change the vendor and product IDs to whatever is reported by `lsusb`:

```
❯ lsusb | grep Huawei
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:15c1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. ME906s LTE M.2 Module
❯ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/huawei-me906s.rules
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="15c1", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}!="3", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}:="0"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="15c1", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}!="3", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'sleep 1; echo 3 > %S%p/bConfigurationValue'"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="15c1", ATTR{cdc_ncm/ndp_to_end}=="N", ATTR{cdc_ncm/ndp_to_end}:="Y"
❯
```

Comment: This answer is similar to a given answer from 2022.